# Pandas : Group by similarities

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have this kind of data :

```
Item    Properties
A   C001
A   C002
A   C003
B   C001
B   C003
C   C001
```

I want to group those items into something like this

```
A   C001, C002, C003
B   C001, C003
C   C001
```

And then, I want to match those item based on properties similarities:

```
A   B   2
A   C   1
B   C   1
```

How can I modify this dataframe using pandas ? I did use groupby method but it display number of properties instead of array of properties name.

Comment: What is the type of column for grouped dataframe? What is type of `C001, C002, C003` ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar For the group dataframe, first column should be list of item, second column should be list of properties that belong to respective item

Comment: I think Anand is asking you for the result of `df.Properties.dtype`.

Comment: Are you interested in the intermediary output (with items grouped) or only in the final output (with items matched)?

Comment: @IanS I'm interested with the final output. The first output i just already get using `groups`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

selfjoin = pd.merge(df, df, on = 'Property')
similarity = selfjoin.groupby(('Item_x', 'Item_y'), as_index=False).size()
```

Comment: Looks promising, i will try it first

Comment: Ok almost like what I wanted. I accept this answer.